# anacron fails, crontab succeeds with automysqlbackup

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, cron

After installing and configuring [ppadial/automysqlbackup](https://github.com/ppadial/autoMySQLBackup) the following results occur in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
anacron:
    /etc/cron.daily/runmysqlbackup:
    run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.daily/runmysqlbackup: Exec format error
    run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/runmysqlbackup exited with return code 1

crontab:
    /etc/cron.daily/runmysqlbackup: 1: /etc/cron.daily/runmysqlbackup: !/bin/sh: not  found
    Parsed config file "/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf"

    # Checking for permissions to write to folders:
    base folder /var/backup ... exists ... ok.
    backup folder /var/backup/db ... exists ... writable? yes. Proceeding.
    chown: invalid option -- 't'
    Try 'chown --help' for more information
```

runmysqlbackup:

```
!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/automysqlbackup /etc/automysqlbackup/myserver.conf

chown root.root /var/backup/db* -R find /var/backup/db* -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \; find /var/backup/db* -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

Ideally, neither of these messages would occur! How to get there from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Your interpreter is unknown so it does not no how to execute, as indicated by the error

> !/bin/sh: not 
>   found

Putting a hash at the start of the first line should address your issue.

What you probably want is

```
chown root.root /var/backup/db* -R
find /var/backup/db* -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \; 
find /var/backup/db* -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```